# Bootstrap 4 tooltips not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting bizarre results with my tooltips. They are not centered properly.

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uf0epmxm/6/

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. I reproduced it in the fiddle. You can see that it is not centered when you hover over the "Add Role" button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-modal="http://laraback.dev/roles/add" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add">Add Role</button>
```

One thing I noticed is if I remove the top blue navbar entirely it centers correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why you are using  `flex-grow: 1;` on your `.content` class? Placement is fixed for me when I removed it.

Comment: I use `flex-grow: 1;` because I want `.content` to take up the rest of the width of the page. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using flex: 0 0 250px on the sidebar and flex: 0 0 auto on the content div instead of min and max width.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move the button like this?

```
<div class="col">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-modal="http://laraback.dev/roles/add" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add">Add Role</button>          
</div>
<div class="col text-right">
    <h1 class="display-5">Roles</h1>      
</div>
```

I think it can be caused by the size of the container.

You can use data-placement in the attribute like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add">Add Role</button>
```

Just to change the tooltip place.